# position wordpress plugins in dashboard on the left hand side

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi sorry if this has been answered before but I have tried googling it  but have not foung what I am looking for. I have managed to build a word press plugin but have no idea to move its position on the dashboard to just under tools can any one point me in the right direction

Comment: The documentation for the function you're using has the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this function

```
    add_menu_page($themename, $themename, 'administrator', basename(__FILE__), 'mytheme_admin');
```